# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8

Tags: python

`SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd0' in file C:\Myr.py on line 23, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details` Код спокойно запускается с отладкой в Visual Studio,но в командной строке - нет.На 23 строчке есть русские символы.

Answer (score 6):

Помогло добавление строчки `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у вас файл в кодировке cp1251. Нужно или пересохранить в кодировке utf-8, или добавить в начало комментарий с указанием фактической кодировки:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в начало файла добавить :
 `#!/usr/bin/python

  # -*- coding: utf8 -*-`

или:`#!/usr/bin/python

 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Ссылка на документацию https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: Не помогло,тоже самая ошибка

Comment: может здесь https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-graphics/thread2207902.html